# GCD of polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

$f$ and $g$ are polynomials over field $\space \mathbb{Z}_3$. $f=X^4+X^3+X+2, \space g=X^4+2X^3+2X+2$. And I been asked to find the GCD of them.

What I have done is using Euclidean algorithm. After long division I get, 
$$X^4+2X^3+2X+2=(1)(X^4+X^3+X+2)+(X^3+X)$$

So GCD$(f,g)=X^3+X$, however the answer to this is $X^2+1$. I want to know what I did wrong.

Comment: You have done *one step* of the Euclidean Algorithm. Repeat, using $X^4+X^3+X+2$ and $X^3+X$. And repeat until you get remainder $0$.

Comment: oh damn, how can I make such a mistake... The next step I did is $1 $ div $X^3+X$ which give me 0, so I think $X^3+X$ is a GCD.

Comment: No, it does not end there. When you divide, you get remainder $2X^2+2$. So there is at least one more step.  In fact exactly one, since $2X^2+2$ does divide $X^3+X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for the completeness, ever step is done by long division.

$$X^4+2X^3+2X+2=(1)(X^4+X^3+X+2)+(X^3+X) \\ 
X^4+X^3+X+2 = (X+1)(X^3+X)+(X^2+1)(2) \\ 
X^3+X = (2X)(2X^2+2)+0$$

Therefore, the GCD of $f$ ad $g$ is $X^2+1$.